# Floating Action Button Not In Bottom Right

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, gravity, floating-action-button

My FAB for some reason won't go to the bottom right corner of the screen as usual. I'm inside a fragment and that fragment is a coordinator layout (I don't know if this is a good practice or not).

Here is the layout xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gigstudios.polls.fragment.MyPollsFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_36dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linear_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And for some reason the FAB ends up in the top right instead of the bottom right. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Btw the xml preview has always shown the fab button in the bottom right corner but when I run it on my phone it's in the top right instead.**

**Edit:** Here's my main_activity xml to show where I'm putting the fragment (The "container" FrameLayout).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGrey">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container">
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: just add android:layout_gravity="bottom|end", Remove all other gravity related tags

Comment: Try adding extra FrameLayout  see my Answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is coming due to `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` add one more field  `android:fillViewport="true". Issue was coming as your`NestedScrollView` was not expanding to match parent or take available space. Working fine tested with my code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: please check above edited answer, its working fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Remove the lines

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/linear_layout"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

on your `FloatingActionButton`. They aren't doing anything (since you are anchoring to a view that fills the entire `CoordinatorLayout`). This will cause your `layout_gravity` to be respected and your `FloatingActionButton` will be placed in the bottom right corner of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: I did that and it still doesn't work. Btw the xml preview has always shown the fab button in the bottom right corner but when I run it on my phone it's in the top right instead.

Comment: Does your `MyPollsFragment` you are using this layout in actually fill the screen? Or is does it have `wrap_content` for its height in the layout you place it in?

Comment: Yes, it fills the screen. I'll add my main activity xml to show where I put my fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"` from your floating action button `xml` code...it will work