# Floating button not floating in bottom right with post refs

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android

30 hours into android and getting into the cooler stuff now.  I tried following this post [Floating Action Button Not In Bottom Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954354/floating-action-button-not-in-bottom-right)

My code is the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".base.ActivityContactList">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contact_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/underline"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16px"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_icon3"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/contact_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have two issues

- My icon is not the bottom right.
- My icon has some turquoise color surrounding the purple plus and the purple plus is tiny.  I am not sure why.

Here is a picture:

[image]

I created the icon view "New -> Image Asset" and then choosing clipart with theme custom so I could set the color.

Comment: Instead of a ConstraintLayout use a CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **My icon is not the bottom right**

Since you are using `ConstraintLayout` you need to set the required constraints. In your case

```
layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

So your Floating action button will become

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16px"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

> **My icon has some turqoise color surrounding the purple plus and the purple plus is tiny. I am not sure why.**

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html?utm_campaign=io15&authuser=2&utm_medium=blog&utm_source=dac), by default it takes the color set in styles.xml attribute colorAccent.

- The background color of this view defaults to the your theme's colorAccent. If you wish to change this at runtime then you can do so via setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList).

So you can change the background by using the following two methods

1. in XML, **app:backgroundTint**

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_margin="16px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
   ```
2. Programmatically, **.setBackgroundTintList**

   ```
    mFab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(your color in int));
   ```

Comment: The default background color is `colorSecondary` not `colorAccent`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti the documentation says so. I double checked this by running it.

Answer (score 2):

1. If You are Using `ConstraintLayout` You can do this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus_icon3"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Now the icon will be in the bottom right corner. You should see a warning in your XML layout file: `This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints`. In  `ConstraintLayout` You always have to set at least one horizontal and vertical constraint. Otherwise, it will jump to the `0` coordinate.

---

2. Turquoise color is Your `colorAccent` in colors.xml file. To change it add:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
```

to the `Floating Action Button`.

Comment: The default background color is `colorSecondary` not `colorAccent`

Comment: [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button#CreateFAB) *By default, the FAB is colored by the `colorAccent` attribute,*

Comment: Check the [updated doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md#regular-and-mini-fab-key-properties). Not only. In the Material Components Theme you **shoudn't** use the accentColor.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/..." />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

About the color make sure to:

- use the the latest stable `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`
- use a **`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`** as app theme

Comment: I was using a constraint layout so the below answers worked better for me than the CoordinatorLayout HOWEVER, your tip on Theme, OMG, awesome!  I didn't know that existed.  Trying to play with right now and struggling as not sure what files they are referring to in the docs, but hopefully I'll get there!! thanks!

Comment: @DeanHiller You can start [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme)

Comment: Mariotte lol, I was on that page but it never mentions the file names so I had to search for content.  It was a hard to follow tutorial(for a newb) BUT in the end, I realized android studio 4 did all that for me actually but it gave me some really good insight into the theme aspect of android development which is super nice.